# How to insert values in descending order into a LinkedList in O(n log n) complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have to implement a custom ProperyQueue and I decided to use a LinkedList as a container for my values. The order in which are to be inserted is high value - low priority. Therefore the queue has the values in a descending order and the priority ascending as the element' values are smaller. How to implement the insertion method to use a complexity of O(n log n) ?

This is the priority queue :

```
public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Comparable {
    private LinkedList<E> queue;
    private int size;


    public PriorityQueue(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public PriorityQueue() {
        this(50000);
    }

  public void insert(E value) {
        if (queue.size() == size) {
            try {
                throw new SizeLimitExceededException();
            } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else {
            queue.add(value);
            size--;
        }
        Collections.sort(queue);
        Collections.reverse(queue);
    }

}
```

The complexity of my insertion method is O(n pow(n)) how can I improve it , what algorithm should I use ?

Comment: Why not using java.util.PriorityQueue or java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue? or at least have a look of how it is implemented?

Comment: Why do you need to reorder your list at each call? it is supposed to be sorted already, you could inject your item at the right place instead using Collection.binarySearch to get the index then do a add(index, item) on your list

Comment: Insertion of a single element in a linked list costs O(N), so you can get better than O(N²).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use a `TreeSet`?

The `compareTo` method of the individual elements should first compare the priority (returning a negative value for a higher priority) and then some compare on the other attributes in order to make them unique.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that really solved my problem !